# How to get raw key data from passphrase and PBKDF2 iterations

Tags: sqlcipher

In [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-api/) it is possible to provide a database key in two ways: either as a passphrase (with an associated number of PBKDF2 rounds) or as a raw key.

I am trying to find a way get the raw key (given as a 64 character hex string) given the passphrase (an arbitrary string) and number of rounds.  I assume the solution lies in somehow performing the PBKDF2 key derivation myself, but I'm not too familiar with how this might work, or if it would produce a value that I could just feed as a raw key to `PRAGMA KEY`.  In addition, the PBKDF2 function appears to take a salt, which I do not know.  If I have to, I am sure I can dig into the sqlcipher source code to figure this out, but I'm hoping that there might already be a simple way to do this that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details on SQLCipher key derivation can be found [on the design page](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/design/). The salt is stored in the first 16 bytes of the database file. You would then use the salt along with the passphrase with an appropriate number of PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1 rounds (64,000 for SQLCipher 3, 4,000 for earlier versions)

Comment: after reading this, am i correct in thinking that if you use a raw key there is no random salt in the 16 bytes of the file, so you couldn't just do something like pre-compute the hashed key and treat it like a raw key, because they aren't decrypted quite the same way?

Comment: When using a raw key SQLCipher does not perform key derivation. There is still random data at the start of the file but it is not used. Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Migrating from user specified passphrases to a form of vaulted raw keys, but in the interim (before existing databases get migrated) want a solution that will work either way.  May just detect whether a given passphrase is really a raw key or not and specify the pragma accordingly.

Comment: That is probably the easiest approach. You could certainly reproduce the same key derivation functionality outside of SQLCipher, but then it would be entirely redundant, and depending on what API you used, it could be much slower as well. If you are using SQLCipher 2 or 3 you'd also need to generate the HMAC key as well in order for everything to work cohesively. In my opinion it would be far easier just to just use the built in key derivation, then, when you switch to the vaulted key approach, rekey the databases.